# Removing a class from ALL matched form elements.. cleanest way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, methods, chaining

I'm trying to clear a bunch of error styling on form elements whenever top level radio buttons are checked.  I'm trying to find:

- Alternative methods and structure for improving performance
- A chaining method for finding all the form elements so I'm not making so many calls.. (not sure if possible).

  // Global variable OR scoped variable defined just before calling functions below..

JS

```
var target = jQuery("#cachedElement");


function functionWithManyReferencesToTarget() {
    target.find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("formError error-state");
});
target.find("label").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("formError error-state");
});
target.find("select").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("formError error-state");
});
}
```

Comment: it looks like you've got a tyop, it should probably be: `var $target = jQuery('#cachedElement');`

Comment: thanks, sorry I actually did not mean to use $target, nor did I mean to set $(this) to a var inside every .each()!  Updated that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$target.find('input, label, select').removeClass('formError error-state');
```

Comment: You _might_ get a tiny performance improvement by using `"input.formError.error-state, label.formError.error-state, select.formError.error-state"` to only hit the needed elements

Comment: @JimDeville correct! I'll leave that up to the OP. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 2):

[`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) iterates over all the matched elements, and [you can use commas (`,`) to separate multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), so your calls could be reduced to:

```
$('#cachedElement').find('input, label, select').removeClass('formError error-state');
```

Comment: +1 This would have the exact same effects as the original code, ie keeping the class `formError` on a `<div>`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just do something like:

```
$('.formError').removeClass('formError error-state');
```

Comment: Fair enough. Changed to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

This makes it an oneliner:

```
jQuery("#cachedElement").find("input, label, select").removeClass("formError error-state");
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
(function($){
    var $target = $('#cachedElement'); // This is confusing

    $target.find('input, label, select').removeClass('formError error-state');
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

using the super `chaining` feature of jQuery the code can be cleaned as below:

```
   jQuery("#cachedElement").find("input, label, select").each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("formError error-state");
   });
```

which hardly makes it a one liner javascript code. Hope this helps you in better maintaining your code.